# using base class in interface

Tags: c#, class, interface

I have one base class:

```
class BaseClass{ }
```

I want to implement interface, that uses base class:

```
public interface IClass
{
   BaseClass GetValue();
}
```

and then create child classes, that implemented this interface, but in method returned thier own type of class:

```
class Child: BaseClass, IClass
{
   Child GetValue(); 
}
```

How can I do that correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use generics:

```
public interface IClass<T> where T : BaseClass
{
   T GetValue();
}
class Child: BaseClass, IClass<Child>
{
   Child GetValue(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not so easy. The way you would expect it to work doesn't because any class implementing `IClass` must *exactly* implement the method from the interface (If you've got an instance of IClass, how would you know that the static type returned by GetValue() is Child? There are workarounds using Generics, but they may be not so nice to use, i.e.

```
 public T GetValue<T>();
```

where you can exactly specify the type you want to have returned. This, however, may get really ugly if used in combination with virtual overloads. Another alternative is creating a new implementation:

```
class Child: BaseClass, IClass
{
    BaseClass IClass.GetValue(); 
    new Child GetValue();
}
```

Like this, you get a `BaseClass` if the static type of the object in the call is `IClass` and a `Child` if it is statically a `Child`.

Remember that

```
IClass a = new Child();
Child b = a.GetValue(); // Error: Cannot convert BaseClass to Child
```

will never work, since the *static* return type of IClass.GetValue() is BaseClass.